# Can a variable reference another variable inside the vars file?

Tags: ansible

I want to build a path inside the vars file itself (I know I can do this from the tasks file). How would that work?

This is what I have now:

```
backup-location: /mnt/cassandra-backup/
schemas-location: schemas/
tokens-location: tokens/
```

And I'm building the path from the tasks file this:

```
- name: Create schemas location
  file:
    path: "{{ backup-location }}{{ schemas-location }}"
    state: directory
```

I would like to have something like this:

```
backup-location: /mnt/cassandra-backup/
schemas-location: "{{ backup-location }}"schemas/
tokens-location: "{{ backup-location }}"tokens/
```

And the tasks file would have this:

```
- name: Create schemas location
  file:
    path: "{{ schemas-location }}"
    state: directory
```

Comment: You could have just tried it in the time it took you to write up a SO question. Anyway, don't name variables that look like subtraction expressions; [the correct variable names are like in Python](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.7/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#creating-valid-variable-names)

Comment: @MatthewLDaniel I don't have infrastructure atm to test this, just writing the playbook. Anyway, I was using the quotes in the wrong place from what I see in the accepted answer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It'd work like this:

```
schemas-location: "{{ backup-location }}schemas/"
tokens-location: "{{ backup-location }}tokens/"
```